# Jquery click works the first time but not the second

Tags: jquery

My problem is like the title says that my click fires the first time when i click on the "hello number 2" div.header. The first one is disappears and is removed from the DOM. Then at the end a new one appers. I don´t understand why it doesn´t repeat the same procedure when i click on the "hello number 3" header.

Thanks in advance.
Here´s a fid.

http://jsfiddle.net/h8S9w/2/

```
    var x = 3;
    var newDiv;
    var firstHeader;
    var firstInfo;
    var lastHeader;
    var lastInfo;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div.header').click(pseudoakkordeon);
    });
    function pseudoakkordeon(){
            x += 1;
            active = $(this);
            firstHeader= $('div.page div.header:first-child');
            firstInfo = $('div.page div.info:first-child');
            lastHeader = $('div.page div.header:last-child');
            lastInfo = $('div.page div.info:last-child');
            $('div.info').stop(true, true).slideUp(1000);
            active.next().stop(true, true).slideDown(1000, function(){
                firstHeader.slideUp(300, function(){
                    firstHeader.remove();
                    firstInfo.remove();
                    newDivx = $('div.page').append('<div class="header"> <p>Hallihalo Number ' + x + '</p></div><div class="info"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hen</p></div>');

                    $(newDivx).live('click', pseudoakkordeon);
                });
            });
    };
```

Comment: You are binding a new delegated event handler everytime you click. As a sidenote live() is deprecated and removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace the click method by the on method. So the code is now :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'div.header', pseudoakkordeon);
});
```

Have a look too to your fiddle with this new code : http://jsfiddle.net/h8S9w/5/

**Edit** : I replace the `:first-child` by the `.first method`. Have a look to this new fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/h8S9w/7/

Comment: It works like intended but every time i click on the next header the first div should disappear and a new one at the bottom appears. It works the first time but then no new one appears and the first one is not disappearing.

Comment: If my answer could help you, you can validate it.

Comment: Sorry if i wasn´t clear. Sadly it´s not working. The animation is working as it should but nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

you can change

```
firstHeader.slideUp(300, function()
```

to

```
$(document).slideUp(300, function()
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn´t change anything. Doing the same thing than before.

Comment: be sure to define your variable out of function , make it global variable.

Comment: It´s still not changing anything.

Comment: Your page save three div everytime you click the newest one replace old one

Comment: you can change      firstHeader.slideUp(300, function()  to $(document).slideUp(300, function()